(Flutter) appbar not appear in the emulator
I wrote this code but the app-bar does not appear in the emulator. why does this happen?
I tried many solutions to solve this problem, need the app-bar to appear in the emulator app.
void main() {
    //Text text = Text('Hello World');
    runApp(HelloWorldApp());
}

class HelloWorldApp extends StatelessWidget {
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
            //home:Text('Hello World'),
            home: Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(),
                body: Center(child: Text('Hello Max')),
            ), // Scaffold
        ); // MaterialApp
    }
}


can you add @override at top of build method

Try adding something in Appbar like title or something otherwise it will not show anything.

First add necessary @override Before build method.
2ndly Add some data inside AppBar() widget like title.
Example:
class AppBarExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppBarExample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
title: Text("Example App"),),
    );
  }
}

